# Will G++ compiler optimize integer division with subsequent multiplication?

Tags: c++, math, g++, compiler-optimization

I have an integer division A/B which mathematically results in A/B - A mod B due to truncation.
I actually want this behavior to compute some indexes, but this results in the following expression  which I don't know how will translate to machine code:

`int c = (a/b)*b;`

Will this expression be optimized into `int c = a`, thus breaking my program?

Comment: A conforming compiler wouldn't transform a program in a way that alters its observable behavior. The "optimization" you contemplate is observable, therefore invalid.

Comment: I wouldn't call such a behaviour an optimisation but an error.

Comment: "Round down to the nearest multiple of `b`" is perhaps more naturally expressed as `a - a % b`

Comment: if your program is well defined the optimiser shouldn't change its observable behaviour. If it does then your program probably wasn't well defined or very rarely you've found a compiler bug

Comment: @IgorTandetnik: Fun fact: GCC can optimize `a / b * b` to `a - a%b` on x86 where that's more efficient, but can't optimize `a - a%b` to `a/b * b` on ARM where that's more efficient.  (for both signed and unsigned.)  ARM doesn't have a modulo instruction, it has a `mls` (multiply-subtract) to generate remainder from dividend, divisor, and quotient.  https://godbolt.org/z/obdj7sYxz .  So for best performance across x86 and ARM with real compilers (at least GCC), write `a/b * b`.

Comment: `a/b * b` seems a bit more natural to me, especially for signed inputs: it's easy to see it truncates toward 0 for signed, vs. having to think through the signs of the remainder.  (Or what I actually did, look at the compiler output to see it made the same asm.)

Comment: In case it isn’t clear, `a / b * c` is interpreted as `(a/b)*c`. Multiplication and division group left to right.